# Best way to create an Installer for windows application

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am creating an Installer for my application 
This installer should be able to:
1 Add Windows Registry settings
2 Create install folders. User should be able to select destination folder
3 Contain settings for all tools which are part of the customer license key
4 The Installer should be available on our customer Support Portal
5 Read settings from a customer specific config.txt file

Now Since I am new to creating Installers, my question is can all these things be achieved using "Visual Studio 2017" ,

Also are their any other Tools freely available to create installer. ??

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Maybe you can try [Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=visualstudioclient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects). For more info, you can refer to this [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1492b1/creating-an-msi-package-for-C-Sharp-windows-application-using-a-v/)

Comment: while doing installation it should read a settings from one file(may be text)  from ftp location